# Determining which Resource Bundle to use in Java 8

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I have 3 Resource Bundle (RB) properties file: `RB_en, RB_fr and RB`. I set a default Locale of "`en_US`" and now I use `getBundle("RB", new Locale("fr"))` to get value for a key "**key1**". I know that Java will look first for the properties file RB_fr, but if the key "**key1**" is not found in `RB_fr`, then in which oder will it continue looking? the `RB_en` file or `RB` file?.

So here some demo code:

RB.properties: 
key1 = valueRB

RB_en.properties:
key1 = valueRB_en

RB_fr.properties: key2 = valueRB_fr

```
 Locale fr = new Locale("fr");
 Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
 ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("RB", fr);
 b.getString("key1");
```

I read a book, the OCP Java SE 8 Programmer II, it said that the order will be `RB_fr -> RB_en -> RB`. But when I run a test, the order it shown was `RB_fr -> RB`, the `RB_en` even didn't take into account. So this make me a bit confused, can anyone explain me which order is correct?

Comment: Can you show us your test code? The order should actually be as described in the book. Do you _assume_ your default locale is `en_US` or do you _know_?

Comment: Hi, I set my default locale to be 'en_US'

Comment: Hi @Marvin, I just edit the post to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to distinguish between missing *bundles* and missing *keys*.

You are first requesting the French resource bundle using [`getBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-java.lang.ClassLoader-). This lookup is indeed as described in the book and in the corresponding javadoc:

> getBundle uses the base name, the specified locale, and the default
>   locale (obtained from Locale.getDefault) to generate a sequence of
>   candidate bundle names.
>
> ...
>
> getBundle then iterates over the candidate bundle names to find the first one for which it can instantiate an actual resource bundle.

Since `RB_fr.properties` is present, it will find and instantiate that.

You are then requesting the value for key `key1` using [`getString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getString-java.lang.String-). But other than `getBundle` this does not have a fallback to a default locale. It looks in the current bundle and in any parents only:

> Gets a string for the given key from this resource bundle or one of its parents.

The parent of your French bundle is the base bundle (i.e. `RB.properties`), which explains why you are not seeing the English value (the *parent chain* is also explained in some detail in `getBundle`'s javadoc linked above).

You would observe the expected behaviour if you were e.g. looking for a German resource bundle:

```
ResourceBundle b = ResourceBundle.getBundle("RB", new Locale("de"));
b.getString("key1"); // valueRB_en
```

In that case `getBundle` would not find any `RB_de.properties` and fall back to `RB_en.properties` where `key1` is present and would be returned.